# Double value in Google chart not working

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

Following google chart works for me, because values are `integer`:

```
google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
        var Value1 = '@Model.Value1';
        var Value2 = '@Model.Value2';

        var tdata = new google.visualization.DataTable();

        tdata.addColumn('string', 'Years');
        tdata.addColumn('number', 'Values');
        tdata.addColumn({ type: 'string', role: 'tooltip', 'p': { 'html': true } });

        tdata.addRow(['1', Value1, createCustomHTMLContentYear1()]);
        tdata.addRow(['2', Value2, createCustomHTMLContentYear2()]);

        var options = { title: 'Value diagram for year' };

        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(tdata, options);
    }
```

`createCustomHTMLContentYear1` and `createCustomHTMLContentYear2` are my custom functions.

But, when values are in `double` type, it doesn't work. I used `parseInt(Value1)`, but in that case, double value lose. For example, **0.3333** turns **0**.

How can I change my code to show `double` values on diagram?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart?csw=1#Configuration_Options

Comment: I converted it to ToString("F4"), then converted back to float again. it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you inputting your numbers as strings?

```
var Value1 = '@Model.Value1';
var Value2 = '@Model.Value2';
```

should be

```
var Value1 = @Model.Value1;
var Value2 = @Model.Value2;
```

assuming that `@Model` refers to a server-side data element.  Then you don't have to worry about type conversion.

If, for some reason, you must enter the numbers as strings, then the proper type conversion function is parseFloat, not parseInt:

```
tdata.addRow(['1', parseFloat(Value1), createCustomHTMLContentYear1()]);
tdata.addRow(['2', parseFloat(Value2), createCustomHTMLContentYear2()]);
```

You only need to do one of these, not both.

Comment: Code in my question was working fine with '' symbols. I had problem with double numbers. Because, numbers was 0.33333333.... Firstly I converted it string with "F4" formatting, then to float. it worked. İn any case I accept your answer for 'parseFloat'. thanks

Comment: Inputting the numbers as strings can cause problems in some of the visualizations (PieCharts come to mind as one example), which is why I recommended converting to numbers instead.